# How to Achieve LR Pacing logic in JETER

Tags: jmeter

Hi I need to use LR pacing logic in JMeter(Start new iteration at Fixed/Random intervals, every XX second(s) can  somebody tell me how to achieve this type of pacing in JMETER

Answer (score 0):

"Pacing" is LoadRunner's mechanism to set the desired number of requests per second, it's inconvenient and ugly, there are way better options in JMeter like:

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

However if you really need to implement this "pacing" in the same way you can use [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer) like it's described in [How to Easily Implement Pacing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter)